# Canon LiDE 120 - Issues with Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1, drivers, scanner

Good day everybody,

I am having issues getting my Canon LiDE 120 scanner working with my Windows 8.1 (64bit) PC. I have tested the device using a Windows 7 PC and it worked fine there. I also know that several people have also got it working on Windows 8.1 devices so the issue must be with my PC. I would greatly appreciate any advice that will help me get the scanner to work!

After contacting Canon support I was told that the issue lies with Windows, and not the scanner itself. Using my event log, they got this:
"Every occasion when you try to install or plug in the Scanner to this computer the Windows documents the source of the problem":
The description for Event ID 123 from source Microsoft-Windows-DeviceSetupManager cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

- **The Issue**

Simply put, the PC seems to have trouble communicating with the scanner, with it often displaying error codes: 2, 156, 182, 55 and 77. I have tried a number of different programs to scan my documents and pictures but the problem persists.

- **Below are some examples of what happens:**
- The scanner does not 'react' to my request to scan something (Via
  software or physical buttons on device)
- The scanner 'warms up' and remains in this mode for a couple of
  minutes before displaying (some of) the errors above.
- The scanner warms up, begins to scan and manages to scan anything up
  to (about) 90% of the scanning surface before failing and displaying
  the above errors again.
- **What I have tried**

  1. Installed accompanying software with the included 'Installation CD'.
  2. Downloaded the entire content of the installation CD directly from the Canon website.
  3. Downloaded the 'Driver' only via Canon
  4. Plugged in the device to Windows and let it download the Driver on its own.
  5. I have tried VueScan (Free), Windows Fax & Scan, Scan (Windows 8.1 App).
  6. Uninstalled all traces of previous scanner (A HP Scanner)
  7. Used Revo Uninstaller after every uninstall
  8. I reset my PC and reinstalled Windows 8.1 - again, to no avail.

Thank you for your time, I look forward to your posts!

Comment: It seems that `Microsoft-Windows-DeviceSetupManager` event 123 is an informational message along the lines of "The DSM service was delayed by x seconds for a driver query/download/install on device y".  That's not in itself a problem, but if it was a very long time it would be a sign (like the fact that your event descriptions are missing) that there might be some other problem with your system.

Comment: When you say "displaying error codes: 2, 156, [...]" what do you mean? Are these coming from a particular program? They're not useful without any context. Even if you don't know what program is displaying the message, a screenshot might help someone figure it out.

Comment: Oh, something like this from the scanner driver probably: http://community.usa.canon.com/t5/General-Printer-Discussion/Canon-LiDE-120-Error-message-quot-Cannot-communicate-with/td-p/139470

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with the USB communication to the scanner. Try a different USB cable, a different USB port, etc. I know that earlier Canon LiDE scanners are pretty fussy about the USB, and came with shielded USB cables with ferrite chokes and would sometimes refuse to work with unchoked cables that worked fine with all sorts of other devices.

Comment: Hey there, Rakslice, I am unsure as to how I can reply to your earlier comments and question. I actually commented on that thread you gave a link for (Username Pollai). I do not have many similar cables to the one provided with the scanner but with the one I tried, the problem persisted. I have also tried every single port possible on the PC :/